# Can anyone identify this Biplane flown Army Air Reserve stationed at Clover Field, Santa Monica, California in mid the 1920's?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification, biplane

Can anyone identify this biplane flown by the 476th pursuit squadron "The Black Falcons" of the 322rd pursuit group of the Army Air Reserve stationed at Clover Field, Santa Monica, California in the mid to late 1920's? My grandfather was a member.

[image]

Comment: According to [this PDF](http://ww41.usafunithistory.com/PDF/0400/476%20PURSUIT%20SQ.pdf), their "Weapon System" was the [PT-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_PT-1_Trusty), but the PT-1 at Wikipedia doesn't look like the plane in the picture.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like an [Airco DH.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.4)

Struts shape and distribution,
wing's dihedral,
open cowling engine configuration,
exhaust line,
propeller shaft's "height" relative to cowling,
slope of the vertical stabilizer's leading edge,
left upper wing aileron compensators, seem to match.

[image]
([source](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/fc/73/d6/fc73d62be3b27cfff77e3a5e61fd81c3.jpg))